# MacOS 'open'-command for GNU/Linux

Tags: linux, macos

MacOS has a neat `open` command:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html

Does GNU/Linux have a similar command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Linux is configurable, as `Slowki` says.  However, that means that the answer is **Yes.**.  Linux is configurable so **it has *at least five* commands** that are equivalent to this.   Did you think that Linux developers would ignore such an idea?  ☺

- GNOME used to have `gnome-open`.
- GNOME now has `gvfs-open`.
- KDE has `kde-open`.
- XFCE has `exo-open`, which uses the desktop's [preferred applications](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/exo/preferred-applications) settings.
- The FreeDesktop people have [`xdg-open`](http://portland.freedesktop.org/xdg-utils-1.0/xdg-open.html), which will try to invoke one of the preceding four, or attempt to perform something appropriate itself.

Of course, these are all predicated upon having a "desktop environment" of some sort.  They all consult their various desktop environments' "settings" databases.  (There's a rough agreement across several desktop environments about the settings databases.)  But then so is your question, as MacOS 10's `open` is also predicated upon a desktop.

However, that doesn't mean that the TUI world is lacking similar tools.  The [`run-mailcap`](http://www.tin.org/bin/man.cgi?section=1&topic=run-mailcap) command operates from the `mailcap` and `mime.types` settings files, for example.  However, the TUI world is a subject better treated by a separate question.

### Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34434/
- [*`xdg-open`*](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xdg-open).  Arch Linux wiki.

Answer (score 0):

No, Linux is too configurable for that, on OSX you start off with Safari, the OSX File Manager, etc, but on my laptop right now I don't even have graphical and I work purely in TTY, to get an open command on Linux to work it would need to be told how to handle every file, which at that point I might as well just make my own.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -d $1 ]; then #Check if $1 is a directory
    nautilus $1 #To be honest pcmanf is way better
fi
if [ -f $1 ]; then #Check if $1 is a file
    if [ $1 == *.txt ]; then #Is the extension .txt?
        gedit $1
    fi
fi
```

I personally prefer to alias the file extensions, so I can just type to path to the file and it will open it, decompress it, compile it, etc, it's one of the better features of ZSH, I recommend you try it.